# How do I check in Swift if a variable with a datatype of URL is empty?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to check if my url is nil or not since I have a background thread that is getting the url from my database.

I tried doing this `travelURL.absoluteString == ""` and `travelURL != nil` but the problem still persists.

I declared my variable as `var travelURL: URL!`

Comment: What problem still persists? Show more relevant code in your question fully demonstrating your issue. And please clarify what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if let` syntax:

```
if let url = travelURL {
    // Here you can use url, it is not nil
} else {
   // Here url is nil 
}
```

Comment: Yep! Just modified